# Python: Trying to extract and output rows from one csv file to another csv file

Tags: python, csv, output

As per the title, I'm attempting to write a python script to read a csv file, filter through it to see which ones I need and output the filtered rows into a seperate csv file.

So far I am able to read the csv files with:

```
open('list.csv') as f
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
```

and I am storing 3 of the rows in a tuple and using it to compare it to another list to see if there is a match. If there is a match I want the row containing the tuple to output to a new csv file.

I have successfully been able to read the files, match the tuples with another list and output which have been matched as text. The problem is I do not know how to then output the rows that match the tuple into a new csv file.

I was thinking to assign a row number to each tuple but that did not go anywhere either.

I want to know the best way I can effectively output the rows I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using csv module, this could be a solution more elegant:

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as inp, open('output', 'w') as outp:
    csv_f = csv.reader(inp)
    csv_o = csv.reader(outp)
    for line in csv_f:
       if line == 'something':
            csv_o.writeline(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open both files. Iterate through the lines in the file that you read from and case your condition evaluates to True, then write the line to the output file.

```
with open('list.csv', 'r') as rf:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as wf:
        # Read lines
        for read_line in rf:
            if <your condition>:
                # Write to the file
                wf.write(read_line)
```